# É certo criar uma viewmodel para cadastro (post) e outra para consulta (get) de uma entidade Usuário?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, view, viewmodel

Estou dando meus primeiros passos em Web API. Criei uma ViewModel da entidade Usuario, vou usá-la para cadastro de usuários. Agora, quando for retornar os dados, tem campos, como a senha, que eu não quero retornar no JSON da Web API. Eu deveria criar outra ViewModel para essa finalidade, ou há outra solução?

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver em busca de de segurança para sua Web.Api, esconder somente a senha não é o única coisa que você deve fazer. E se for levar em conta o conceito DRY ter duas entidades exatamente iguais com a diferença de um objeto ter um campo a mais que o outro já não é boa ideia.

Porém, existe um framework chamado JWT (Json Web Tokens)

o JWT é um padrão aberto (RFC 7519) que define um modo compacto e auto-contido para transmitir de forma segura informações entre partes como um objeto JSON. Essas informações podem ser verificadas e confiáveis ​​porque são assinadas digitalmente. Os JWTs podem ser assinados usando uma key (com o algoritmo HMAC) ou um par de chaves público / privado usando o RSA.

Deixa eu explicar mais alguns conceitos desta definição:

Compacto: Devido ao seu tamanho menor, JWTs podem ser enviados através de um URL, parâmetro POST, ou dentro de um HTTP header. Além disso, o tamanho menor significa que a transmissão é bem mais rápida.

Auto-contido: A carga contém todas as informações necessárias sobre o usuário, evitando a necessidade de consultar o banco de dados mais de uma vez.

Quando devemos usar JSON Web Tokens?

Aqui estão alguns cenários onde JSON Web Tokens se faz muito útil:

Autenticação: Este é o cenário mais comum para usar JWT. Uma vez que o usuário estiver conectado, cada solicitação subseqüente incluirá o JWT, permitindo que o usuário acesse rotas, serviços e recursos que são permitidos com esse token. Single Sign On é um recurso que usa amplamente JWT hoje em dia, devido à sua pequena sobrecarga e sua capacidade de ser facilmente utilizado em diferentes domínios.

Intercâmbio de Informações: JSON Web Tokens é uma boa maneira de transmitir informações de forma segura entre as partes, porque como elas podem ser assinadas, por exemplo, usando pares de chaves públicas / privadas, você pode ter certeza de que os remetentes são quem dizem ser. Além disso, como a assinatura é calculada usando o header e o payload, você também pode verificar se o conteúdo não foi adulterado.

O que é a estrutura JSON Web Token?

JSON Web Tokens consistem de três partes separadas por pontos (.), Que são:

Header
Payload
Signature

Portanto, um JWT normalmente se parece com o seguinte.

xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

Vamos entender melhor cada um desses blocos:

**Header**

O header consiste tipicamente em duas partes: o tipo do token, que é JWT, e o algoritmo de hashing sendo usado, como o HMAC SHA256 ou RSA.

Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, este JSON é Base64Url codificado para formar a primeira parte do JWT.

**Payload**

A segunda parte do token é o payload, que contém as claims. As claims são declarações sobre uma entidade (normalmente, o utilizador) e metadados adicionais. Existem três tipos de claims: claims reservadas, públicas e privadas.

Claims reservadas: trata-se de um conjunto de claims predefinidas que não são obrigatórias mas recomendadas, para fornecer um conjunto de claims úteis e interoperáveis. Alguns deles são: iss (emissor), exp (tempo de expiração), sub (assunto), aud (público) e outros.

Observe que os nomes de claims são apenas três caracteres de comprimento como JWT é destinado a ser compacto.
Claims públicas: Estas podem ser definidas à vontade por aqueles que usam JWTs. Mas para evitar colisões eles devem ser definidos no registro IANA do JSON Web Token ou ser definido como um URI que contém um espaço de nomes resistente a colisões.

Claims privados: tratam-se de claims personalizadas criadas para compartilhar informações entre partes que concordam em usá-las.

Um exemplo de carga útil pode ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Signature** (Assinatura)

Para criar a parte de assinatura você tem que tomar o header codificado, o payload codificadoo, um segredo, o algoritmo especificado no cabeçalho, e assinar isso.

Por exemplo, se você quiser usar o algoritmo SHA256 HMAC, a assinatura será criada da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A assinatura é usada para verificar se o remetente do JWT é quem ele diz que é e para garantir que a mensagem não foi alterada ao longo do caminho.

**Juntando Tudo**

A saída é de três seqüências Base64 separados por pontos que podem ser facilmente passados ​​em ambientes HTML e HTTP, sendo mais compactos quando comparados com padrões baseados em XML, como o SAML.

A seguinte imagem mostra um JWT que tem o header anterior e payload codificados, e é assinado com um segredo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você quiser brincar com o JWT e colocar esses conceitos em prática, você pode usar o [Debugger do jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io) para decodificar, verificar e gerar JWTs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como funcionam os JSON Web Tokens?**

Na autenticação, quando o usuário fizer logon com suas credenciais com êxito, um JSON Web Token será devolvido e deve ser salvo localmente (normalmente em armazenamento local, mas também podem ser usados ​​cookies), em vez da abordagem tradicional de criar uma sessão no Servidor e retornando um cookie.

Sempre que o usuário deseja acessar uma rota ou recurso protegido, o agente do usuário deve enviar o JWT, normalmente no cabeçalho de Autorização usando o esquema Bearer. O conteúdo do header deve ser semelhante ao seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é um mecanismo de autenticação sem estado, uma vez que o estado do utilizador nunca é guardado na memória do servidor. As rotas protegidas do servidor verificarão se há um JWT válido no authorization header e, se estiver presente, o usuário poderá acessar recursos protegidos. Como JWTs são auto-suficientes, toda a informação necessária está lá, reduzindo a necessidade de consultar o banco de dados várias vezes.

Isso permite que você confie inteiramente em APIs de dados que são apátridas e até mesmo fazer solicitações para serviços downstream. Não importa quais domínios estão servindo suas APIs, portanto, Compartilhamento de Recursos de Origem Cruzada (CORS) não será um problema, pois não usa cookies.

O diagrama a seguir mostra esse processo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Por que devemos usar JSON Web Tokens?**

Vamos falar sobre os benefícios do JSON Web Tokens (JWT) quando comparado a Simples Web Tokens (SWT) e Assertion Security Markup Language Tokens (SAML).

Como o JSON é menos detalhado do que o XML, quando é codificado, seu tamanho também é menor, tornando o JWT mais compacto do que o SAML. Isso torna a JWT uma boa escolha para ser passada em ambientes HTML e HTTP.

Em termos de segurança, o SWT só pode ser simetricamente assinado por um segredo compartilhado usando o algoritmo HMAC. No entanto, os tokens JWT e SAML podem usar um par de chaves público / privado na forma de um certificado X.509 para assinatura. Assinar XML com XML Digital Signature sem introduzir furos obscuros de segurança é muito difícil quando comparado com a simplicidade de assinatura do JSON.

Os JSON parsers são comuns na maioria das linguagens de programação porque mapeiam diretamente para objetos. Por outro lado, XML não tem um mapeamento de documento para objeto natural. Isso torna mais fácil trabalhar com JWT do que asserções SAML.

Quanto ao uso, JWT é usado na escala de Internet. Isso destaca a facilidade de processamento do JSON Web token no cliente em várias plataformas, especialmente móveis.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a comparação do comprimento de um JWT codificado e um SAML codificado.

Se você quiser ler mais sobre JSON Web Tokens e até mesmo começar a usá-los para realizar autenticação em seus próprios aplicativos, [vá até a página do JWT](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/) e aprenda tudo o que precisa.